# Counting number of nodes below an element

Tags: xml, linq

How to count number of xml descendants for each xml element, i.e:

```
<Person >
    <Name >Paxton</Name>
    <City >Munich</City>
    <Age >29</Age>
 </Person>
 <Person >
    <Name >Mike</Name>
    <City >Orlando</City>
     <Age >33</Age>
```

I mean first Person has 7 nodes below itself, Name has 5 noes etc..
I tried using

> ```
>   element.Descendants().Count()
> ```

but this returns only childs unfortunately.

Comment: Why does `Name` have 5 nodes below itself? For me there is only one node: A `TextElement` node containing the text `Paxton`.

Comment: City, Age, Name, City, Age

Comment: XML is a hierarchical data format, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need `element.Elements().Count()`. If element is a Person node, it will return number of person's elements. I.e. `3` for your sample xml (Name, Age, City). [XElement.Elements()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) will return only direct descendants of element. [XElement.Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) will return all children on any level.